# mongo BadValue unknown operator: $or

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

The collection has one document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54b513933aca242d9915a787"),
    "carriers" : [ 
        {
            "carrier" : ObjectId("54b54d223aca242d9915a788"),
            "carryingInterval" : {
                "from" : ISODate("2013-12-31T23:00:00.000Z"),
                "to" : null
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to make a criteria, that is looking for a certain carrier and range.
The **carryingInterval**'s **from** and **to** fields could be a **Date** object or **null**. The **null** value means +/- infinity.

My criteria is:

```
{
    carriers: {
        $elemMatch: {
            carrier: ObjectId('54b54d223aca242d9915a788'),
            carryingInterval: {
                $or: [
                    {
                        from: {$lt: Date()},
                        to: null
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This query cannot run with the following error message:

> *Can't canonicalize query: BadValue unknown operator: $or*

Okey, I tried other criterias, like this:

```
{
    carriers: {
        $elemMatch: {
            carrier: ObjectId('54b54d223aca242d9915a788'),
            $or: [
                {
                    "carryingInterval.from": {$lt: Date()},
                    "carryingInterval.to": null
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

It runs without any result however the **from** field is less then 'now' in the document. If I skip the **from** field from the criteria, i get it.

In this [topic](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/hNgue4NZqtI) Will Berkeley says

> $or should be on the top level

but in my second criteria the **$or** operator isn't on the top level, that is below the **$elemMatch** operator, and it works.

I don't understand this behavior. Please, explain me! Thx! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `Date()` returns a string, not a `Date`; use `new Date()` to create a `Date` object of the current time.

So your query object needs to look like this instead:

```js
{
    carriers: {
        $elemMatch: {
            carrier: ObjectId('54b54d223aca242d9915a788'),
            $or: [
                {
                    "carryingInterval.from": {$lt: new Date()},
                    "carryingInterval.to": null
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

`$or` can be used within `$elemMatch` because it effectively creates a new top-level query object with respect to the elements of `carriers`.

Comment: Thank you, it works!
I knew that in a standard javascript environment the **new Date** creates the **Date** object with the **new** operator.
But it confused me that ObjectId doesn't use the **new** operator in the pure mongo shell.
Can you show me a well detailed mongo documentation, because a lot of helpful issues are missing from the official documentation such as the _top level_ issue.