# Validator in MongoDB does not work

Tags: mongodb, validation

I recently started working with MongoDB (version 3.2.9) and wanted to try the validation capabilities it had, as I like database-level consistency.

I know I can, and should only, do this validation in the business logic, as I already do. 
But it feels nice having an additional layer of security.

I tried adding a collection `category` with an `_id` of type `'int'`, `name` of type `'string'` and `desc` of type `'string'`.

These values should all exist, but restrictions on the content are not given.

Now, following the [manual](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document-validation/), I ended up with the following code:

```js
db.createCollection('category', {
  validator: { $or:
    [
      { _id: { $and: [ { $exists: true },
                       { $type: 'int' } ] } }, 
      { name: { $and: [ { $exists: true },
                        { $type: 'string' } ] } }, 
      { desc: { $and: [ { $exists: true },
                        { $type: 'string' } ] } }
    ]
  }
})
```

However, with this simple structure already, MongoDB complains:

```js
{ "ok" : 0, "errmsg" : "unknown operator: $and", "code" : 2 }
```

---

Now, I have found [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28002055), but just went and tried to put multiple constraints directly inside the `$or` arrays:

```js
db.createCollection('category', {
  validator: { $or:
    [
      { _id: { $exists: true } },
      { _id: { $type: 'int' } }, 
      { name: { $exists: true } },
      { name: { $type: 'string' } }, 
      { desc: { $exists: true } },
      { desc: { $type: 'string' } }
    ]
  }
})
```

But now, while it does create the collection like it should, I can now execute any of the following `insert` commands:

```js
db.category.insert({})
db.category.insert({_id: 17, name: '', desc: 'valid'})
db.category.insert({_id: 42, name: 42, desc: ''})
db.category.insert({_id: 43, name: '', desc: 42})
db.category.insert({_id: '', name: 42, desc: 42})
```

`db.category.find()` now returns

```js
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57e19650b10ab85eca323684") }
{ "_id" : 17, "name" : "", "desc" : "valid" }
{ "_id" : 42, "name" : 42, "desc" : "" }
{ "_id" : 43, "name" : "", "desc" : 42 }
{ "_id" : "", "name" : 42, "desc" : 42 }
```

As a last resort, I tried changing the `$or` operator to an `$and`, as it should need all rules to be valid, not just at least one.

```js
db.createCollection('category', {
  validator: { $and:
    [
      { _id: { $exists: true } },
      { _id: { $type: 'int' } }, 
      { name: { $exists: true } },
      { name: { $type: 'string' } }, 
      { desc: { $exists: true } },
      { desc: { $type: 'string' } }
    ]
  }
})
```

With this approach which seems the most rational to me, it however does not work **at all**. No matter which of the above mentioned `inserts` I tried using, mind you there's one valid out of the 5, none works, all giving me the same error:

```js
WriteResult({
        "nInserted" : 0,
        "writeError" : {
                "code" : 121,
                "errmsg" : "Document failed validation"
        }
})
```

As stated above, a call to `db.version()` returns `3.2.9`, and I am running the default MongoDB 64-bit distribution on a Windows machine with only the `--dbpath` parameter set to a previously empty directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please provide the 32-bit integer value using the function `NumberInt()`. Otherwise, it is interpreted as Double.

The following insert should successfully insert a document into collection.

**Success scenario:-**

```
db.category.insert({_id: NumberInt(17), name: "aaaa", desc: "valid"})
```

**Failure scenario:-**

```
db.category.insert({_id: NumberInt(42), name: 42, desc: ''})
```